# Parse JS: Provided Master Key, but Parse doesn't seem to recognize it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, parse.js

I'm using a Distinct query, but it isn't working and I get the following error on my console:

`Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided.`

I actually provided my Master Key, App Key and Javascript Key like required in the Javascript Documentation:

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY", "YOUR_MASTERKEY");

//javascriptKey is required only if you have it on server.

Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse'
```

I really do not understand why it isn't working.

Here is the query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Card);
        query.distinct("identifier")
          .then(function (results) {
            console.log(results)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
```